# Background task in Flask + Gunicorn without Celery

Tags: python, flask, celery, telegram, background-process

I want to send a telegram notification when the user performs a specific task in my flask application. I'm using [`python-telegram-bot`](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot) to handle telegram. Here's the simplified code:

```py
@app.route('/route')
def foo():
    # do some stuff...
    # if stuff is completed successfully - send the notification
    app.telegram_notifier.send_notification(some_data)

    return ''
```

I'm using [`messagequeue`](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Avoiding-flood-limits) from `python-telegram-bot` to avoid flood limits. As you might have expected, that's not working and I'm getting the following error:

```
telegram.ext.messagequeue.DelayQueueError: Could not process callback in stopped thread
```

I tried to launch it in a separate daemon thread but I also ended up with that error.

This functionality is used only once in the entire application so I want things to be simple and don't want to install more dependencies like Celery.

Is there a way to achieve this using threads or some other simple way?

### EDIT (more code)

Here's simplified implementation of the telegram bot:

```py
from telegram import Bot, ParseMode
from telegram.ext import messagequeue as mq


class Notifier(Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Notifier, self).__init__('my token')
        # Message queue setup
        self._is_messages_queued_default = True
        self._msg_queue = mq.MessageQueue(all_burst_limit=3, all_time_limit_ms=3500)
        self.chat_id = 'my chat ID'

    @mq.queuedmessage
    def _send_message(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(Notifier, self).send_message(*args, **kwargs)

    def send_notification(self, data: str):
        msg = f'Notification content: <b>{data}</b>'
        self._send_message(self.chat_id, msg, ParseMode.HTML)
```

In the app factory method:

```py
from notifier import Notifier


def init_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.telegram_notifier = Notifier()

    # some other init stuff...

    return app
```

The thing with threads I tried:

```py
@app.route('/route')
def foo():
    # do some stuff...

    # First method
    t = Thread(target=app.telegram_notifier.send_notification, args=('some notification data',), daemon=True)
    t.start()

    # Second method
    t = Thread(target=app.telegram_notifier.send_notification, args=('some notification data',))
    t.start()
    t.join()

    return ''
```

Comment: Yes, you can achieve that just with threads. Can you provide more verbose example of your code? Looks like there is a problem in how you start that thread and how you are calling the callback.

Comment: I added some more code, you can check it out. Sorry for the long response time ://